# Dynamic Div creation asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to create Div dynamically on the press of button click.

For that i refered this link>> http://forums.asp.net/t/1349244.aspx

and made code on server side(.cs page) as follows>>

```
public static int i = 0;
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        HtmlGenericControl newControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");

        newControl.ID = "NEWControl"+i;
        newControl.InnerHtml = "This is a dynamically created HTML server control.";

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(newControl);
    }
```

This code was giving me just one div each time when i press the button., I wanted to have addition of divs.

On client side using javascript also i tried>>

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" OnClientClick="addDiv();" />

    </div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addDiv() {
        alert("Control comming in function");
        var r = document.createElement('Div');
        r.style.height = "20px";
        r.style.width = "25px";
        r.appendChild("div");
        alert("Control going out of function");
    }
</script>
```

Both of these didnt work.

What mistake am i making?

Is there any thing wrong?

Comment: check your page Is it getting refreshed each time?

Comment: yeah it is getting refreshed. why?

Comment: then each time it will create new!!!      it's causing postback

Comment: mag ajax update panel waparun pahu ka?

Comment: hey, now i have kept my controls in ajax update panel , and page is not getting refreshed, still the same result.@Prasad

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/182512/Adding-and-deleting-div-dynamically-in-JavaScript look this project

Comment: @Prasad Dhanyawad, Prasad Bhau.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
    public int Index
    {
       get
       {
          if(ViewState["Index"]==null)
          {
             ViewState["Index"]=0;
          }
          else
          {
             ViewState["Index"]=int.Parse(ViewState["Index"].ToString())+1;
          }

          return int.Parse(ViewState["Index"].ToString());    
       }
   }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl newControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        newControl.ID = "NEWControl"+Index;
        newControl.InnerHtml = "This is a dynamically created HTML server control.";

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(newControl);
    }
```

Comment: There is some problem second last line i.appendChild("div"); Its not printing last alert.

Comment: which code you are using? Mine one? I have not used i.appendChild("div") line. I have used i.appendChild(r)

Comment: yeah, i have tried that also >>  i.appendChild(r) ..it also not worked

Comment: I think so, because last alert i.e. alert("Control going out of function"); is not showing. If i place it above i.appendChild(r); , its showing me the alert. Means,  i.appendChild(r); must have problem.

Comment: Are you using firefox's firebug, or chrome console? They will show you the exact error

Comment: One more thing, try changing "Div" to "div"(small d) for create element

Comment: firefox. k i will try it with div.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26610/discussion-between-pawan-nogariya-and-pakk-puneri-porag)

Answer (score 1):

It is giving you one div, cause you are adding one div.
Remember that asp.net needs you to create all dynamically added controls on very PostBack after that.

If you want two controls you have to add two to the PlaceHolder.

Comment: but i dont know how many divs user will create? so i cant predict about number of placeholders.

Comment: One place holder, but when you know the number, say on a button click, then you have to keep track of it. Then use that to create the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one parent div with some ID(predefined lets say `id="dvDynamic"`) and `runat="server"`

and then use it the `dvDynamic.innerHTML = "<div> /* dynamic div contents */ </div>"`

Its the simplest way, as if you are using html element in ASP.net use dom controls for better generation. Dynamic creation of control will require handled, interface and many things to co-ordinate with that control. As its not predefined by system. you have to create it.

SO choose the DOM element option. that is faster and better :)

I hope this will help :)

Comment: means instead of creating div server side, i should create it on aspx page only?

Comment: Yes :) and then use it in back end code. that will reduce your work and will be easy to code further :)